# Does erlang-ls support go-to-definition for variables?

Tags: erlang, erlang-ls

Does [erlang-ls](https://github.com/erlang-ls/erlang_ls) support go-to-definition for variables?

Going to definition seems to work for functions and modules, but Coc.vim says "provider not found" when I `gd` on a variable name. Cmd-clicking a variable name doesn't do anything in VSCode, either.

### What I tried:

- erlang-ls docs and issues
- Peeking through the source, I see that [els_code_navigation](https://github.com/erlang-ls/erlang_ls/blob/c4a64f8931bcc1eb2a6e4e07454a8b2bb635e43f/src/els_code_navigation.erl) matches on poi_kind. The relevant poi_kind would be [`variable`](https://github.com/erlang-ls/erlang_ls/blob/c4a64f8931bcc1eb2a6e4e07454a8b2bb635e43f/src/els_code_navigation.erl), but "variable" doesn't appear in els_code_navigation.

Comment: There is currently no support in `erlang_ls` for jumping to the definition of a variable. If this is something that you would like implemented please open a feature request in the [`erlang_ls`](https://github.com/erlang-ls/erlang_ls/issues) GitHub project.

Comment: Thanks! If you post as an answer, I can mark correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no support in `erlang_ls` for jumping to the definition of a variable.

If this is something that you would like implemented please open a feature request in the [`erlang_ls`](https://github.com/erlang-ls/erlang_ls/issues) GitHub project.